# How to rewrite java code without use of labels?

Tags: java, coding-style, label

```
categoryCheck: {
        for (String allowedCategory : allowedCategories) {
            if (evt.getLoggerName().startsWith(allowedCategory)) {
                break categoryCheck;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Is it any ideas how to rewrite this code without using labels and without considerable increasing of it?

Comment: simple break is enough, as there are no nested loops

Comment: That will cause it to return false;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd probably put it into its own method:

```
// I've guessed at the types...
public boolean isCategoryAllowed(Event evt, Iterable<String> allowedCategories) {
    for (String allowedCategory : allowedCategories) {
        if (evt.getLoggerName().startsWith(allowedCategory)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then change the calling code to simply call the method:

```
if (!isCategoryAllowed(evt, allowedCategories)) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct equivalent using a boolean flag:

```
    boolean found = false;
    for (String allowedCategory : allowedCategories) {
        if (evt.getLoggerName().startsWith(allowedCategory)) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        return false;
    }
    // ...the rest of the method's code...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean matched = false;

for (String allowedCategory : allowedCategories) {
    if (evt.getLoggerName().startsWith(allowedCategory)) {
        matched = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!matched)
    return false;

// else continue with the rest of the code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag.

```
boolean found = false;
for (String allowedCategory : allowedCategories) {
    if (evt.getLoggerName().startsWith(allowedCategory)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!found) 
    return false;
```